# Nginx configuration for angular and codeigniter in sub folder

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

I have a following folder structure
in folder `/usr/share/nginx/html/myapp.com/`

```
-app
-bootstrap
-index.html
-pages
-rest
--application
---controllers
----api
----- Rest classes
----- .....
--system
--vendor
--index.php
```

And this is my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.com;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp.com;

    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp.com;
        try_files $uri/ $uri index.html =404;
    }

    location /rest/ {
            alias  /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp.com/rest/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
           }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 444;
    }
}
```

nginx access log

```
 - - [10/Oct/2016:18:27:01 +0200] "GET /rest/api/users/sessionData HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "http://myapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" "-"
 - - [10/Oct/2016:18:27:01 +0200] "GET /rest/api/users/sessionData HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "http://myapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I'm keep getting 444 errors for all php requests. Can you please help me to set my nginx.conf correctly. If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.com;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp.com;

    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp.com;
        try_files $uri/ $uri index.html =404;
    }

    location /rest/ {
        alias  /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp.com;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /rest/index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 444;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the following code,

```
http {
   ...
   map $request_uri $rot {
      "~/rest" /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp.com/rest/;
      default /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp.com/;
   }
   map $request_uri $ind {
      "~/rest" index.php;
      default index.html;
   }
   ...
   server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  myapp.com;
        rewrite ^/rest(.*) $1 break;
        root   $rot;

        index  index.html index.htm index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri/ $uri $ind =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include fastcgi_params;
        }           
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: sorry, but now even angular html is not visible...404 Not Found

Comment: well its empty :D
but access logs looks like this
 - - [11/Oct/2016:10:21:00 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" "-"